# difference between functions for getting the last element in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to solve the problem in the minimum number of characters, but the testing system does not want to accept the code with `last`, only `!!`. What's the difference between `last someList` and `someList !! (length someList - 1)`? Data.List is imported.

Comment: Write your own implementations of `last` and `!!` and `length`, and see for yourself.

Comment: They are equivalent. Depending on optimization, I expect `someList !! (length someList - 1)` to be slower since it scans the list twice instead of only once. That can make it a bad consumer since the list can not be immediately garbage collected while the first scan is running.

Comment: `head (reverse someList)` is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this does seem pretty obvious, but I was sufficiently curious about this question to confirm it using QuickCheck. For non-empty lists, there indeed appears to be no difference whatsoever between `last someList` and `someList !! (length someList - 1)`. For empty lists, both expressions result in errors; I *suppose* you could highlight the fact that the resulting error messages are different, but even so I’d argue that this doesn’t constitute any real difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is no difference. Error in the testing system =)

Answer (score -1):

[`last` is implemented by `foldl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#last) and [`(!!)` by `foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#%21%21). I *suppose* its order of evaluation causes different results.